# How to change the Text in textarea on typing javascript automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Text area field when I enter the text in textarea the data should automatically change

As soon as I enter text the color should automatically keeps on changing to green color 
code:

```
<td colspan="2">
    <textarea id="text" rows="10" cols="100" onClick="green();"></textarea>
</td>
```

I tried this code not working

```
<script>
function green() 
{
    document.getElementById("").style.color="#000000";
}
</script>
```

**this is the entire code :**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AUTO EMAIL</title>
<style>
            table {
              font-family: arial, sans-serif;
              border-collapse: collapse;
              width: 50%;
            }

            td, th {
              border: 1px solid #dddddd;
              text-align: center;
              padding: 8px;
            }

            tr:nth-child(even) {
              background-color: #dddddd;
            }
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <table align=center>

          <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <textarea id="text" rows="10" cols="100" onClick="green();"></textarea>
                </td>
          </tr>

    </table>

<script>
function green() 
{
    document.getElementById("text").style.color="#000000";
}
</script>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Why `document.getElementById("")` not  `document.getElementById("text")`?

Comment: I have passed it not working

Comment: I added a snippet

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if you pass text to your selector and pass different color except from black because default color of text is black.

```js
function green() 
{
    document.getElementById("text").style.color="green";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text" rows="10" cols="100" onClick="green();"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

add textarea style :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AUTO EMAIL</title>
<style>
            table {
              font-family: arial, sans-serif;
              border-collapse: collapse;
              width: 50%;
            }

            td, th {
              border: 1px solid #dddddd;
              text-align: center;
              padding: 8px;
            }

            tr:nth-child(even) {
              background-color: #dddddd;
            }
             textarea {
                color: green;
            }
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <table align=center>

          <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <textarea id="text" rows="10" cols="100" ></textarea>
                </td>
          </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both other answers are not wrong but are either not clear enough or over complicate a simple solution.

Lets start with just setting the textarea's text color to green by default:

```
<textarea id="text" rows="10" cols="100" style="color:green;"></textarea>
```

now all text in the textarea will be green by default.

Your onClick solution is working as intended but it is ON CLICK meaning text being inserted does not generate a function call thus making that solution not relevant to your needs.